# Using DomainClassPropertyComparator in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

In my grails view the ordering applied on the domain class constraints are not picked when i use f:display with each individual property. I heard that domain class property comparator can be used to order the property display as per the constraints applied on the domain class.

Can some body help me on how to use DomainClassPropertyComparator to sort properties on my view?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the scaffolding templates, edit _form.gsp and change the comparator it is using to DomainClassPropertyComparator e.g. my _form.gsp

```
    <%=packageName%>
<% import grails.persistence.Event %>
<% import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.DomainClassPropertyComparator %>


<%  excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'version' << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated'
    persistentPropNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name
    boolean hasHibernate = pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
    if (hasHibernate && org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(domainClass)?.identity?.generator == 'assigned') {
        persistentPropNames << domainClass.identifier.name
    }

DomainClassPropertyComparator mattsComparator = new DomainClassPropertyComparator(domainClass)
comparator = mattsComparator

props = domainClass.properties.findAll { persistentPropNames.contains(it.name) && !excludedProps.contains(it.name) }
    Collections.sort(props, comparator)
    for (p in props) {
        if (p.embedded) {
            def embeddedPropNames = p.component.persistentProperties*.name
            def embeddedProps = p.component.properties.findAll { embeddedPropNames.contains(it.name) && !excludedProps.contains(it.name) }
            Collections.sort(embeddedProps, comparator)
            %><fieldset class="embedded"><legend><g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" /></legend><%
                for (ep in p.component.properties) {
                    renderFieldForProperty(ep, p.component, "${p.name}.")
                }
            %></fieldset><%
        } else {
            renderFieldForProperty(p, domainClass)
        }
    }

private renderFieldForProperty(p, owningClass, prefix = "") {
    boolean hasHibernate = pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
    boolean display = true
    boolean required = false
    if (hasHibernate) {
        cp = owningClass.constrainedProperties[p.name]
        display = (cp ? cp.display : true)
        required = (cp ? !(cp.propertyType in [boolean, Boolean]) && !cp.nullable && (cp.propertyType != String || !cp.blank) : false)
    }
    if (display) { %>
<div class="fieldcontain \${hasErrors(bean: ${propertyName}, field: '${prefix}${p.name}', 'error')} ${required ? 'required' : ''}">
    <label for="${prefix}${p.name}">
        <g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${prefix}${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" />
        <% if (required) { %><span class="required-indicator">*</span><% } %>
    </label>
    ${renderEditor(p)}
</div>
<%  }   } %>
```

Comment: tried the above option already. But I am not able to create a new DomainClassPropertyComparator. I am getting no mathcing constructor found error.